# How to find your action in admin-ajax.php file?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-hook

I am using woo commerce plugin for my eCommerce website. There are some order listed on my dashboard. When I change status of an order from processing to completed we click on button.

Here is my action goes:

```
if ( in_array( $the_order->post_status, array('wc-pending', 'wc-on-hold', 'wc-processing') ) )
     $actions['complete'] = array(
         'url' => wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=upen-mark-order-complete&order_id=' . $the_order->id ), 'upen-mark-order-complete' ),
         'name' => __( 'Dispatched', 'dokan' ),
         'action' => "complete",
         'icon' => '<i class="fa fa-truck">&nbsp;</i>'
     );
```

But when I am looking into admin-ajax.php file there is no `order_id` getting. I am confused that where these attributes are we getting to change order status like action, `order_id` etc.

Comment: by looking at `__( 'Dispatched', 'dokan' )`, I can assume this is the implementation of dokan (not that I know dokan) not woocommerce. Can you include where `$actions` array is being used?

Comment: when we click on button to order status then we pass these parameters to admin-ajax.php file mentioned like this url above. But there is no such parameters getting in admin-ajax.php file

Comment: yes... there shouldn't be.. you should look for "upen-mark-order-complete" somewhere in your theme files or plugin that implements this...

Comment: should be something like `wp_ajax_upen-mark-order-complete`

Comment: [read this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action))

Comment: but in url we are passing parameters to admin-ajax.php file

Comment: yes.. that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [wp_ajax_(action)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)).

based on your given code, there should be something like this implemented somewhere... maybe on your theme files or plugin files..

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_upen-mark-order-complete', 'my_action_callback' );

function my_action_callback() {

    $order_id = $_GET['order_id'];

    wp_die(); 
}
```

additionally,
With notepad++ you can search it in your files like this..

[image]

Comment: neither wp_ajax_upen-mark-order-complete nor upen-mark-order-complete is found in all files

Comment: in public_html directory

Comment: where do you have this code? search that folder... if it's in dokan, search dokan folder.

Comment: are you sure this is the correct action? `action=upen-mark-order-complete`?

Comment: I have downloaded the free version of dokan.. and the action is `action=dokan-mark-order-complete`

Comment: search for `wp_ajax_dokan-mark-order-complete` that should be your starting point... I can see it is hooked in function complete_order in file ajax.php located on dokan\classes\ajax.php

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in your themes functions.php

```
function mysite_woocommerce_order_status_completed( $order_id ) {
echo $order_id; exit; // you will get order ID here , when you are updating order status to completed.
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed','mysite_woocommerce_order_status_completed' );
```